# How to set external storage or set a custom path to download maps in OS 10 and OS 11 on Android?

Tags: ios, flutter, sdk, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

How to set external storage or set a custom path to download maps in OS 10 and OS 11 on Android?

I'm using this function with Flutter

SDKOptions sdkOptions = SDKOptions
.withAccessKeySecretAndCachePathCacheSizeAndPersistentMapPath(
sKey,
sSecret,
externalPath,
ConfigurationSingleton.instance.cacheSizeBytes,
externalPath);

where "externalPath" is the custom path external or internal

Comment: What is `externalPath` ? And does it have a value?

Comment: Hi Benjamin. Not really sure if I get the question....Looking at the docs, it's as you said: https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.6.4.0/dev_guide/topics/key-concepts.html#use-sdkoptions-to-set-programmtically-here-credentials-and-cache-path ... is something not working ? If yes, what exactly and what did you try ? See also more details in https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.6.4.0/api_reference/core.engine/SDKOptions-class.html

Comment: externalPath variable  is something like this /stoarge/0/emulated/myfolder, it's just one example

Comment: I could found the problem, I need to declare or create the SDKOptions and set it after to use the mapview, I mean at the startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could found the problem, I need to declare or create the SDKOptions and set it before to use the mapview, I mean at the startup